# Godot 3, multiplying by delta not making the object to move

Tags: godot

I have a simple code which makes a sprite rotate and move,

```
extends Sprite

var vel = Vector2(1,1)

func _ready():
    print(position)
    pass

func _process(delta):
    rotation += PI * delta 
    position = position + vel * delta 
    pass
```

But in the line

```
position = position + vel * delta
```

when I multiply by delta, the sprite doesn't move, when I remove the delta, the sprite moves, why is that? I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hi2yiY-zNxQ) tutorial and it seems to work fine.

Comment: How much is 1 unit?

Comment: @Bálint 1 unit is 1 pixel

Comment: Hi, did you tried with `set_process(true)` in `_ready`?

Comment: @Tapirboy Assuming I understand it correctly, no lifecycle methods in Godot 3.0 require manual enabling. This is only required if you're working with 2.1.

Comment: @TARDISMaker Yes, true,sorry - my bad. So, another thing - can you really multiply a vector with a number (velocity * delta)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since delta time is in seconds, that means the character'll move 1 pixels every second if Godot can even handle sub-pixel values. Try increasing the velocity

Comment: It moves when I increase the velocity, does it mean delta should be used for higher velocities but not required for lower velocities?

Comment: @azemda No, you should define the velocities in pixels/second instead of pixels/frame

Comment: From [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/4yvg96/what_is_the_unit_for_linear_velocity/), once multiplied by delta, it becomes pixels/seconds.

Comment: That's not correct, it becomes pixel per frsme once you multiply it. Measure it if you don't believe ne